# I can't check out SVN project on windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, tortoisesvn, vcs-checkout

On windows 7 Ultimate I can't check out SVN projects or do updates. After clicking checkout project or update it shows a dialog where I put in the project URL and then require me to type in username and password. After that the dialog just hangs
there, with message the bottom "639 bytes transferred, at 0 bytes/s". If I user repo-browser same thing and after one hour it times out (I can browser the repository with a web browser). I can do checkout and updates on XP Mode so I don't think it is a firewall issue.

Comment: sounds like a permission issue, try as administrator.

Comment: Is this on a svn:// or a http:// repo?

Comment: I would guess it's a firewall issue.

Comment: It is a http:// repo. I can get to it via browser but I can't get to it via repo browser. I guess I am stuck with Vista for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using TortoiseSVN?
Do you have to provide a proxy in Internet Explorer or an other browser to connect to the internet?

If both yes, than you have to enter the proxy settings in Tortoise. 
Just go to All Programs -> TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Network.

Tortoise doesn't use the settings that were set in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I don't connect through a proxy but I did used fiddler to test repo browser. The initial request/response works fine. It connects to the server and I get prompted for login/password. The issue is when it tries to get the repository content. Repo browser sends the request but it never gets the response back. I removed the proxy settings after the test and still no luck :(

Comment: It is strange that it works with the browser and not with TortoiseSVN. Maybe you can try an other SVN client (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients) or via de commandline (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.history.html#svn.tour.history.browsing)

Answer (score 0):

1. When you put in the URL, did you make sure the [i]case[/i] matched 100% correctly? SVN used to be a bit problematic in this area, although AFAIK only during write actions.
2. Are you checking out to a local folder where you actually have write permissions? (i.e. not in program files, the root, a custom folder inside %users%, or any other folder where the explorer pretends you have write access but you really don't). The TortoiseSVN client might not trigger a UAC dialog.

Comment: For 1. Yes, the case matches. This URL works in other OSs.

For 2. Yes, I am checking in to my Documents folder. And I tried other locations just in case. The thing is that repo browser doesn't work either. Very strange.